# How can I make it so the script tells me the changes of the .txt file in real time? (Python)

Tags: python, function, loops, printing, txt

So I've been trying to make a code that specifically changes the text in a .txt file in a certain folder - and so far it works. But there's one problem: it won't update in real time (inside the code) until I repeat the code (as in, I choose 'Y'), but when I use the script, it changes in real time outside on the file itself.

```
    #Função
def coca():
   print("Write your anotation:")
   escolha = input()
   arquivo1 = open('doc.txt', 'a')
   arquivo1.write(escolha)
   arquivo1.write(" ")
   print("Your anotation:")
   f = open("DOC.txt", "r")
   print(f.read())
   arquivo1.write("\n")

# Main
x = 0

# Loop
while x < 1:
  coca()
  repetir = input("Do you wish to add anything else to your annotation? Y or N    ").lower()
  if repetir.upper() == 'N':
        print('Goodbye.')
        x = x + 1
```

Basically, say I type an anotation called "***This ivory leg is what propels me, harpoons thrust in the sky***" on the input, when it follows up printing the text, it shows a blank slate (if the file has nothing written on it) OR the contents of the file before I added a new anotation to it - So if I had on the .txt "***Break your backs and crack your oars, men, if you wish to prevail***" the "ivory leg" part wouldn't show up, until I started the code again.

I believe it's because the text will only update once the main code is finished, which means the print function only shows what's currently on the *doc.txt*, since the script hasn't finished yet.

Sorry for my english by the way. It's not my native language!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close your arquivo1 file after writing.

```py
def coca():
   print("Write your anotation:")
   escolha = input()
   arquivo1 = open('doc.txt', 'a')
   arquivo1.write(escolha)
   arquivo1.write(" \n")
   arquivo1.close()
   print("Your anotation:")
   f = open("DOC.txt", "r")
   print(f.read())
   f.close()
```

Now this would work fine.

Comment: Forgot to say thanks. Thanks!